# Правильно ли составлен запрос SELECT с точки зрения строгой документации?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Есть такой запрос, в двух вариантах:

```
SELECT order_id, x as x1, y as y1, MAX(x)+1 as x2, MAX(y)+1 as y2  FROM `all_items` where order_id>0 group by order_id  
SELECT order_id, MIN(x) as x1, MIN(y) as y1, MAX(x)+1 as x2, MAX(y)+1 as y2  FROM `all_items` where order_id>0 group by order_id
```

оба работают одинаково, время выполнения один в один до мс.
Судя по документации, верный только второй запрос, в данном случае мне можно сказать повезло, что x1 и y1 нужны как раз именно минимальные из набора, а если бы нужно было что-то другое, как вытаскивать из отобранных строк остальные столбцы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно классическим стандартам, в списке полей с использованием агрегатных функций, можно указывать только агрегатные функции или поля, по которым проводится группировка. MySQL этом отношении более либерален и позволяет указать любые дополнительные поля. Но значения этих полей (если они различны в пределах группировки) будут выбираться произвольные

Comment: т.е. второй запрос кроме того что полностью соответствует документации, но еще и единственно допустим? как же тогда получать то что нужно? мне нужны первые и последние поля, в моем случае они просто подходят под аггрегацию , а если бы не подходили, а нужно было забрать именно первую строку и последнюю строку из группировки?

Comment: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ROW(col1, col2) = (SELECT col1, MIN(col2) FROM mytable GROUP BY col1) UNION SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ROW(col1, col2) = (SELECT col1, MAX(col2) FROM mytable GROUP BY col1)

Comment: ошибка #1242 - Подзапрос возвращает более одной записи

Comment: Виноват. Вместо **ROW(..) =** нужно **ROW(..) IN**

Comment: вроде ищет, но 0.36сек. мой вариант 0.01сек. интересно, а как из полученных результатов отсортировать еще по разнице (MAX(x)-MIN(x))>50 ? Так не дает отфильтровать, равно как и по условию (ч2-х2)>50...

Comment: HAVING MAX(x) - MIN(X) > 50

Comment: И да, ROW() не дружит с индексами и использованиеROW() порождает полное сканирование таблицы. Можете попробовать заменить его на JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите эту статью про группировку - http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html
там описаны 5 способов, как корректно выбрать данные, для которых не подходит использование агрегатных функций. Конструкций можно написать и больше, но, имхо, они будут другой формой записи перечисленных методов.